# Loop through var_files variables in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower

I have a playbook that calls a role and is supposed to import apache vars for websites. The issue is that when I look into ports.conf I only see the line for website1. Website2 is never called. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
---
- hosts: all
  vars_files:
   - [ "./roles/apache-vhost/vars/website1.yml", "./roles/apache-vhost/vars/website12.yml"]
  roles:
   - apache-vhost
```

/roles/apache-vhost/vars/website1.yml

```
site:
  - domain: website1
    http_port: 5000
    https_port: 6000
```

./roles/apache-vhost/vars/website2.yml

```
site:
  - domain: website2
    http_port: 5001
    https_port: 6001
```

task in playbook is

```
- name: add http Listeners to ports.conf
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/httpd/conf.d/ports.conf
    line: 'Listen {{item.http_port}} #{{ item.domain}}'
  loop: "{{ site }}"

- name: add https Listeners to ports.conf
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/httpd/conf.d/ports.conf
    line: 'Listen {{item.https_port}} #{{ item.domain}}'
  loop: "{{ site }}"
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The variable *site* from the 2nd file website2.yml overrides the value from the 1st file website1.yml, e.g.

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars_files:
    - website1.yml
    - website2.yml
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: site
```

gives

```yaml
  site:
  - domain: website2
    http_port: 5001
    https_port: 6001
```

You'll have to concatenate (merge) the lists in a loop, e.g.

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        site: "{{ site|default([]) + x.site }}"
      loop:
        - website1.yml
        - website2.yml
      vars:
        x: "{{ lookup('file', item)|from_yaml }}"
    - debug:
        var: site
```

gives

```yaml
  site:
  - domain: website1
    http_port: 5000
    https_port: 6000
  - domain: website2
    http_port: 5001
    https_port: 6001
```